# Creating an array by "scanning" another array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

So, what im trying to do, is to make an array of buttons, but only the buttons appear of a previously determined array. im not very good at explaining, so ill make a visual representation of what i mean.[image]

I understand it looks simple, and that i put it together in 5 minutes, but i hope it gets across what im trying to make. i just dont know how to make it.
The squares are supposed to represent buttons. Im trying to make his in a from, In Visual Studio.

This is what ive got so far:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Marble();

    }
    public void Marble()
    {
        int ButtonWidth = 40;
        int ButtonHeight = 40;
        int Distance = 20;
        int start_x = 10;
        int start_y = 10;
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int delX = x + (y * 2);

        for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {

            for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {


                GameButton tmpButton = new GameButton();
                tmpButton.BackColor = Color.Black;
                tmpButton.Top = start_x + (x * ButtonHeight + Distance);
                tmpButton.Left = start_y + (y * ButtonWidth + Distance);
                tmpButton.Width = ButtonWidth;
                tmpButton.Height = ButtonHeight;
                tmpButton.Text = "X: " + x.ToString() + " Y: " + y.ToString();
                tmpButton.MouseUp += TmpButton_MouseUp;
                tmpButton.Row = x;
                tmpButton.Column = y;
                tmpButton.Currentcolor = false;

                if (x == 4 && y == 6) {
                    tmpButton.BackColor = Color.White;


                }


                else
                {


                    this.Controls.Add(tmpButton);
                }

            }

        }

    }


    private void TmpButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GameButton Mygamebutton = (GameButton) sender;
        Mygamebutton.Currentcolor = !Mygamebutton.Currentcolor;
      if (Mygamebutton.Currentcolor == true)
        {
            Mygamebutton.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
      else
        {
            Mygamebutton.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These buttons should appear on a web page, a windows form application, a WPF application or what else?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: is the array size always the same?

Comment: Im planning on adding a config file, where you can change diffent setting inside of the code, while not having to dig through it all. and in that config file you can change the layout & the size of the array

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this requierement using a `TableLayoutPanel` control of the same size of your array.
You will have to use a `for` (or nested for) structure to loop for all your array positions and if inside that position you have the value you need, then you create a Button inside the same position of the `TableLayoutPanel`.

In case that you don´t know the `TableLayoutPanel` control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx

Comment: For this assignment we arent allowed to use the toolbox... thats why im trying to find a different way to create an array.

Comment: To add a TableLayoutPanel you don´t need the toolbox. you can add it programatically

Answer (score 0):

First create all of the buttons :

```
const int BUTTON_SIZE = 40;
int W = ParentPanel.Width / BUTTON_SIZE;
int H = ParentPanel.Height / BUTTON_SIZE;

for (int x = 0; x < W; x++ )
{
    for(int y = 0; y < H; y++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "button_" + x.ToString() + "_" + y.ToString();
        btn.Size = new Size(BUTTON_SIZE, BUTTON_SIZE);
        btn.Location = new Point(BUTTON_SIZE * x, BUTTON_SIZE * y);
        ParentPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

As you've noticed buttons are named like `button_0_1`, `button_0_2` etc.
Now all you have to do is to make simple call:

```
for(int x = 0; x < W; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < H; y++)
    {
        Button btn = ParentPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(ctrl => ctrl.Name == "button_" + x.ToString() + "_" + y.ToString());
        if(btn != null)
        {
            // depending on if arr[x][y] == 1 make your action
        }
    }
}
```